# BackupPc fails with SIGPIPE

Tags: backuppc

I run BackupPc on a Debian Squeeze server.
It backups other Debian Squeeze machines on my LAN succesfully.
I've setup it to backup another Debian Squeeze machine on Wan, but the backup always fails with the error message:

```
Aborting backup up after signal PIPE
Got fatal error during xfer (aborted by signal=PIPE)
```

The backup is executed via ssh, and the configuration of this backup client is:

```
$Conf{RsyncArgs} = [
        # Do not edit these!
            '--numeric-ids',
            '--perms',
            '--owner',
            '--group',
            '--devices',
            '--links',
            '--times',
            '--block-size=2048',
            '--recursive',
        #
        # If you are using a patched client rsync that supports the
        # --checksum-seed option (see http://backuppc.sourceforge.net),
        # then uncomment this to enabled rsync checksum cachcing
        #
        '--checksum-seed=32761',
        #
        # Add additional arguments here
        #
        '-D',
        '--one-file-system',
];
$Conf{FullPeriod} = 6.97;
$Conf{IncrPeriod} = 0.49;
$Conf{FullKeepCnt} = 4;
$Conf{IncrKeepCnt} = 93;
$Conf{XferMethod} = 'rsync';
$Conf{RsyncShareName} = '/';
$Conf{BackupFilesExclude} = [
        '/cdrom',
        '/dev',
        '/files/_nobackup',
        '/floppy',
        '/lost+found',
        '/mnt',
        '/proc',
        '/sys',
        '/tmp/ssh-*',
        '/var/lib/amavis/amavisd.sock',
        '/var/lib/backuppc',
        '/var/lib/nagios3/rw/nagios.cmd',
        '/var/run/acpid.socket',
        '/var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl',
        '/var/run/courier/authdaemon/socket',
        '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
        '/var/run/nut/usbhid-ups-apc_backups_cs500',
        '/var/run/proftpd.sock',
        '/var/run/screen',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/amavis',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/anvil',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/bounce',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/bsmtp',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/defer',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/discard',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/error',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/ifmail',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/lmtp',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/local',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/maildrop',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/odmr',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/proxymap',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/relay',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/retry',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/rewrite',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/scache',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/scalemail-backend',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/smtp',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/tlsmgr',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/trace',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/uucp',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/verify',
        '/var/spool/postfix/private/virtual',
        '/var/spool/postfix/public/cleanup',
        '/var/spool/postfix/public/flush',
        '/var/spool/postfix/public/pickup',
        '/var/spool/postfix/public/qmgr',
        '/var/spool/postfix/public/showq',
        '/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux',
        '/var/spool/squid',
];
$Conf{XferLogLevel} = 1;
$Conf{CompressLevel} = 9;
$Conf{PingMaxMsec} = 200;
$Conf{ClientTimeout} = 3600*8;          # 6 Hours!!
```

I tried a local tar backup to see if there is some issue woth the filesystem, and everything gone fine.

Any suggestions on how to debug ?

Comment: more info needed. Like, how are you backing up ? I'm assuming over ssh ?

Comment: An excerpt of the config would probably be very helpful for us.

Comment: I've edited the original question.
Yes, rsync over ssh.
The config file is now in the question.
Thank you !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've invesitgate on the meaning of sigpipe. As described in [SIGPIPE - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE):

> On POSIX-compliant platforms, SIGPIPE is the signal sent to a process
>   when it attempts to write to a pipe without a process connected to the
>   other end. ...

So I suspected that the trouble was with the `ssh` transport that gets disconnected.

I've setup a longer timeout to `ssh` using the options `-o ServerAliveInterval=300`, in the config:

```
$Conf{RsyncClientCmd} = '$sshPath -o ServerAliveInterval=300 -q -x -l root $host
 $rsyncPath $argList+';
```

Now the backup has complete successfully!

Comment: I had a similar error and I googled and came this page. I also use rsync method and in configuration file I do not have $Conf{RsyncClientCmd} variable. Where(main conf file or client conf file) should I provide the above statement?

Comment: In client conf file if you want to apply this modification only to a specific client. In main conf, if you want this behavior applied globally.

Comment: It doesn't work on my installation. BackupPC 3.3.0

Comment: I had the same error message after deleting a directory listed as to be backed up from the filesystem and not updating the backup list in backuppc FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this is useful to others, we were getting both `aborted by signal=PIPE` and `Child exited prematurely` on some backups (only incremental backups it would seem). Adjusting the `$Conf(RsyncClientCmd)` didn't work for our installation of BackupPc 3.1 on Centos 5 *(soon to be upgraded)*, as it broke the attempt to connect in the first place. We are using `rsync` over `ssh`.

As the machine was dedicated to doing backups and we were concerned about others using ssh access, we simply set `ClientAliveInterval=300` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` on the client machines (not the BackupPc server), but this could have been done for the individual login instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when running backups with BackupPC just because the `RsyncShareName` parameter (that defines which folders should be synced) was not correct: the given folder didn't exist on the server.

You could check at this parameter in the `Xfer` settings.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I finally figured it out. When you define host specific directories to back up for a host and one of these directories does not exist, rsync will fail with message like:

```
Got fatal error during xfer (aborted by signal=PIPE)
```

After removing the directory everything works perfectly without any additional rights on rsync.

Hope my experience will help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

There was some changes in the course of BackupPC version 3.X that was incompatible with rsync 3.2.3

See https://github.com/backuppc/backuppc/issues/369

We had the same problem and solved it by adding `--protocol=28` in the main configuration (Xfer) with the `RsyncArgs` parameter.

Alternatively, you can also edit the config.pl with the following:

```
$Conf{RsyncArgs} = [
  '--numeric-ids',
  '--perms',
  '--owner',
  '--group',
  '-D',
  '--links',
  '--hard-links',
  '--times',
  '--block-size=2048',
  '--recursive',
  '--protocol=28'
];
```

(only the **last line is important**, you might want to keep the rest unchanged)

Then if you have Ubuntu clients, you might want to check with the following arguments:

```
$Conf{RsyncArgsExtra} = [
  '--open-noatime',
  '--no-msgs2stderr'
];
```

on their respective `<name_of_host>.pl` files

For Debian 10 (Buster) servers, you only need to have `--noatime` in their specific config (`RsyncArgsExtra`)